# Python OOP: inefficient to put methods in classes?

Tags: python, oop

I usually use classes similarly to how one might use `namedtuple` (except of course that the attributes are mutable). Moreover, I try to put lengthy functions in classes that won't be instantiated as frequently, to help conserve memory.

From a memory point of view, is it inefficient to put functions in classes, if it is expected that the class will be instantiated often? Keeping aside that it's good design to compartmentalize functionality, should this be something to be worried about?

Comment: The function object for a method is instantiated *once* per class, when the class is defined. Each instance of the class does not receive its own copy of the method.

Comment: Your premise is faulty... You don't save memory by putting lengthy functions in classes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Methods don't add any weight to an instance of your class.  The method itself only exists once and is parameterized in terms of the object on which it operates.  That's why you have a `self` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Python doesn't maintain pointers directly to its methods in instances of new-style classes. Instead, it maintains a single pointer to the parent class. Consider the following example:

```
class Foo:
  def bar(self):
    print 'hello'

f = Foo()
f.bar()
```

In order to dispatch the bar method from the instance f, two lookups need to be made. Instead of f containing a method table to look for bar, f contains a reference to the class object Foo. Foo contains the method table, where it calls bar with f as the first argument. So f.bar() can be rewritten as

```
Foo.bar(f)
```

Answer (score 2):

Instances of a class have one pointer that refers to the class; all other features of the class are unique and accessed through that pointer. Something like

```
foo.bar()
```

really translates to something like

```
foo.__class__.bar(foo)
```

so methods are unique, long-lived objects belonging to the class that take the instance as an argument when called.

Answer (score 2):

Each object has its own copy of data members whereas the the member functions are shared. The compiler creates one copy of the member functions separate from all objects of the class. All the objects of the class share this one copy.

The whole point of OOP is to combine data and functions together. Without OOP, the data cannot be reused, only the functions can be reused.